# Overlay video with video time and/or combining images to video

Tags: linux, video-editing

I have a very long video that I want to overlay with the video time (effectively a clock counting up from 0:00:00 to the length of the video).

Because I can't find any tools to do this exact task, I wrote [a java program](https://github.com/StealthySerpent/MiniProjects/blob/master/com/silentsalamander/MiniProjects/TimeImageGenerator.java) to make 1000s of transparent png images, one for each second. OpenShot (my preferred video editor) can take all images matching a certain naming scheme in a folder and import them as a video while controlling how many frames each image is displayed for. This sounds perfect, except when I tested it with the first thousand images it would freeze on the 500th frame; ie. it would count up to 00:08:19 and then never tick over to 00:08:20.

I tried a few other ways to combine the images into a video (eg. avconv), but I cannot get them to work. btw, Ubuntu is my main OS, but I have access to Windows and Mac if necessary.

How can I combine my 10,000+ images into a single video? Or better yet, is there a more direct way to overlay a video with a timer counting from 0:00:00 to the length of the video?

Comment: How long is your video?

Comment: @Jonno 7 hours 36 minutes, but I might need to do this again with a longer videos in the future so I'm attempting to make the transparent-timer-video about 20 hours long.

Answer (score 0):

[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) will do this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-20:timecode='00:00:00':rate=25,format=yuv420p" -crf 23 -c:a copy -map 0 output.mp4
```

The above code contains special characters and should be escaped as your shell requires,

Alter the `r=25` to the value of your video framerate. `black@0.5` is 50% opaque. See the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#drawtext-1) for more details and options. Alter the CRF value for quality/size tradeoff - lower is better quality.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks! However, timecode='00:00:00' exits with an error; I had to change it to timecode='00:00:00:00' but then its hh:mm:ss:?? frame within the second I think.

Comment: I'll check whether it allows you to skip the frame count.